# Is there a command line version of Windows XP's compression program

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, compression

What is Windows XP's command line built in compression tool? I would like to call it from my batch file.

Comment: On serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/39071/does-windows-have-a-built-in-zip-command-for-the-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If CAB-file is approach see MAKECAB command.

Comment: Care to explain a bit more @Digionica? I don't think I really understand your answer

Comment: You can create cab-archive using this standart command. It's not ZIP but compressed too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want NTFS filesystem-level compression, the command is **`compact`**. (For filesystem-level encryption, it's `cipher`.)

There is no command for creating ZIP archives, but it's possible to create CABs as Digionica noted.